# Using native git not jgit in Eclipse git?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit, aws-codecommit

Is there any way to configure egit to use your native (OS) git and not the jgit implementation? If not, are there any alternative git Eclipse plugins?

**EDIT #1** - I should note, AWS CodeCommit uses a [credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) for auth, from .gitconfig:

```
[credential]
    helper = !/usr/local/bin/aws --profile CodeCommitProfile codecommit credential-helper $@
    UseHttpPath = true
```

I'm guessing this is something specific to CodeCommit and is not in jgit.

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting "git-upload-pack not permitted" when trying to clone a repository. I'm using Amazon codeCommit so the authentication is not the typical username and password.

Comment: EGit uses JGit and cannot be configured to use native Git. [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download.html) comes with a plug-in that uses native Git but I don't know if it can be used outside of Aptana Studio. Other native Git clients I know of don't integrate with the Eclipse workspace. Are you sure that the _git-upload-pack not permitted_ is a shortcoming of JGit that cannot be worked around and will working in native Git?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann "git-upload-pack not permitted" is the error I get when trying to clone a repository. I get other authentication errors when trying to push\pull as well. I think this is because amazon code commit uses IAM auth, and jgit does not work with it for some reason.

Comment: JGit can [fetch and push from/to Amazon S3](http://blog.spearce.org/2008/07/using-jgit-to-publish-on-amazon-s3.html) Not sure if this is the same as _IAM_. If so however, it looks as if the described techinque can be used to authenticate from within EGit as well.

Answer (score 7):

[EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/) strictly uses [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), the Java implementation of Git.

The Git plugin in [Aptana Sudio3](http://www.aptana.com/) seems to be embedded in the product sources ([github.com/aptana/studio3](https://github.com/aptana/studio3)), but uses a native Git.

There is a class [`jgit.transport.AmazonS3`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/AmazonS3.html), as illustrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9566354/6309) and [this one (setting IAM)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28117233/6309).

There is an interesting discussion [in this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=120692) which can offer a clue as to what to patch:

> Having looked at [how JGit access the S3 host](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/fd58cbcdee632100f239423194be9aaa951f7835/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/AmazonS3.java#L552), JGit tries to access the bucket using virtual hosted style requests - `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/` - this request style works fine with buckets in the US Standard zone, but for other regions S3 redirects it with HTTP 307 redirect to the correct region.
>
> It seems that jgit does not handle this HTTP 307 redirect correctly, and will need to implement behavior to correctly handle [redirects by S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your clarifications. See my edit regarding credential helper.

Comment: @javamonkey79 I confirm the credential helper is not part of EGit/JGit: you would need to tweak that credential helper (or deactivate it for test) in order to see if the error persists.