# Pushing local Git repository to remote Google Cloud Repository from inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting a push of the an Eclipse project's local Git repository into a Google Cloud Repository for the first time.

To this end I select `Team` | `Push Branch 'master'` from my Eclipse (Mars) project's context menu in the Eclipse Project Explorer and then provide the following information:

- Remote name: `google`
- URI: `https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/` where `x` is the name of my Google Cloud Platform project
- User: my Google account name of the form `<y>@gmail.com`, i.e. a valid e-mail address
- Password: my Google account password

Next, I am presented twice with a further dialog box that again asks for credentials for the repository at `https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/` (as if the first one would have been rejected, but why?) and I provide the same credentials (User, Password) two more times.

At this point, I run into this error message:

```
Can´t connect to any URI: https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/   
(https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/ not authorized)
```

What could be wrong? Am I supposed to use another credential than the (global) one for my Google Account when pushing to a Google Cloud Repository (as would seem wise from a security perspective), and if so, how could I obtain one? Overall, what is the right recipe for executing this kind of push from inside Eclipse as opposed to on a [command-line](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository)?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it from the [command line](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository) after all:

```
cd <local-git-repository>
# pwd contains .git; try git status
# gcloud init was already run
git config credential.helper gcloud.sh
git remote add google https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/
```

This includes the following effects:

1. Source code now visible inside Google Cloud Repository e.g. from Google Developers Console
2. Remote Git repository now visible inside Eclipse (Mars) as configured remote repository `google: https://source.developers.google.com/p/<x>/`

Comment: I did the same, but each time I try to push to the repository through the IDE it always asks for credentials. Push works only through command line. Any help?

Comment: It looks like the Eclipse Git plugin (EGit) [only uses JGit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29139348/3953357), which currently isn't supported with credential.helper.

Comment: The GCP doesn't accept usernames/passwords to authenticate. It requires access tokens that the credential helper will pass to the GCP.