# Eclipse: setting path to git executable - OS X El Capitan

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I get the error below when I try to push:

> "An internal Exception occurred during push: URI not supported:
>   sso:..."

SourceTree and IntelliJ allow to set git's executable path but not Eclipse which is always **/usr/bin/git**.

Note:

1. My git path is **/usr/local/git/current/bin/git**.
2. I can't symlink it to **/usr/bin/git** due to [SIP](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT204899), and I'm not allowed to disable it.
3. I can't change the URL, it must stay **sso://**.
4. I set  **/usr/local/git/current/bin/git** first thing in $PATH, but Eclipse ignores it.
5. Versions:

   - /usr/local/git/current/bin/git - 2.7.0
   - /usr/bin/git - git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
   - Eclipse - 4.5.2
   - Eclipse EGit- 4.2.0.201601211800-r

The only solution I thought about is to set the path through:
**Eclipse** > **Team** > **Git** > **Configuration**, but I don't know what is the key, if there is any.

Comment: The SSO isn't a standard protocol for Git transfers. Did you mean SSH instead? If not, what is SSO?

Comment: Note that you can create a bare clone locally which you can clone into your working copy.  You can then use unmodified toolings to work and push back into your bare copy, which you can then manually invoke the blessed git binary to push back into the upstream repository.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses EGit exclusively for git operations, which in turn uses JGit which is a port of native git to Java running inside Eclipse itself.

In other words, Eclipse does not rely on any native git on the system.

I would suggest raising an issue with the JGit project for the sso protocol, and use `git push` manually from the command line for the time being.  You should be able to use Eclipse for all other git operations (not involving talking to origin).

See [Using native git not jgit in Eclipse git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29087558/53897) for more detail.